# Qt QML Unit test setup using Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, cmake, qml

I am trying to do unit testing with QtQuickTest and i am receiving some errors and also hitting some walls in including them with the other tests.

Basicly my tst_mytest.cpp file looks like this, taken from: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicktest-index.html

```
// tst_mytest.cpp
#include <QtQuickTest>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

class Setup : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Setup() {}

public slots:
    void qmlEngineAvailable(QQmlEngine *engine)
    {
        engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myContextProperty", QVariant(true));
    }
};

QUICK_TEST_MAIN_WITH_SETUP(mytest, Setup)

#include "tst_mytest.moc"
```

Now this macro QUICK_TEST_MAIN_WITH_SETUP runs the main function, which means that i cannot run it myself in this .exe file (at least i tried and failed), and then i cannot do more than set the context for the engine.

My cmake for this looks like this:

```
set(TEST_QML_EXE "${PROJECT_NAME}_QML_TEST")

add_executable(${TEST_QML_EXE})

target_sources(${TEST_QML_EXE}
PRIVATE
    qml/tst_TestMain.cpp
)

set_property(TARGET ${TEST_QML_EXE} PROPERTY ${PROJECT_NAME}_PRIVATE 1)

target_link_libraries(${TEST_QML_EXE}
PRIVATE
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::QuickControls2
    Qt5::QuickTest  
    Qt5::Qml
)
```

And when i run it, i get

```
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(836)\combase.dll!00007FFA0677B2D7: (caller: 00007FFA0677A15C) ReturnHr(399) tid(1498) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(836)\combase.dll!00007FFA0677B2D7: (caller: 00007FFA0677A15C) ReturnHr(400) tid(1498) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(836)\combase.dll!00007FFA0677B2D7: (caller: 00007FFA0677A15C) ReturnHr(401) tid(1498) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(836)\combase.dll!00007FFA0677B2D7: (caller: 00007FFA0677A15C) ReturnHr(402) tid(1498) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(836)\combase.dll!00007FFA0677B2D7: (caller: 00007FFA0677A15C) ReturnHr(403) tid(1498) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(836)\combase.dll!00007FFA0677B2D7: (caller: 00007FFA0677A15C) ReturnHr(404) tid(1498) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
```

...Repeating errors.

As i found so far this seems to be something to do with not opening an Application instance for running the tests, altho the QML tests i create in the same folder as my tst_*.cpp file does RUN, I just get all these repeating errors on every single file.

Now if only i found out how to run the QUICK_TEST_MAIN_WITH_SETUP macro WITHOUT the MAIN part of it inside, so that i could start a QCoreApplication before in a custom main, i think the repeating errors might disappear, and perhaps i could run all the backend tests in the same executable, which would be perfect.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `CoInitialize(nullptr);` to initialize COM.
COM = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Comment: I tried to call it inside the Constructor of my Setup class and still i get the same repeating errors.

Comment: You need to call this before anything else is used that uses COM. What it does is that it load dll files that are needed to work with COM. If your constructor runs after the first COM based functionality then it will not work
If you call this in a constructor it may be called more than once? You only need to call CoInitialize(nullptr); on startup, then everting else for COM works

Comment: Thank you for your continued reply. I understand what this CoInitialize(nullptr); is supposed to do, and it seems that the best place to put it would be in the start of main. My problem is that i am trying to use Qt Quick Test macro QUICK_TEST_MAIN_WITH_SETUP (or even without SETUP, same problem) which runs its own main loop, and thus i cannot seem to get it to do CoInitialize(nullptr); anywhere as the only impact i get to have on the test framework is through the Setup class. Any way around this?

Comment: I did a search for the macro and this might something similar? https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qmltest/quicktest.h.html .
If you write the same code but add the CoInitialize(nullptr); first and in the end you should call `CoUninitialize();`.
I havent worked with Qt and its test logic but it should be possible to write your own main. Most need to write code to init tests and all test frameworks will allow that.